# How to continue batch processing after invoking stop() on Spark Streaming Context

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming

We are working on a paper about the efficiency of Spark Batch/Stream Processing. We try to detect anomalies in large sets of data, what we need is that when which log line undergoes which process.

Therefore, we created a simulation of events, that, before and after each process, we record the time that line has arrived/left that stage.

But a problem we face is that we do not want the time we analyze the stream processing be included in those calculations. So what we basically need is to

Do some calculation with streaming,
invoke `ssc.stop(false,true)` (via HTTP or detecting the end of the file),
Continue processing the analytics about the performance

But the problem with Spark is that it wouldn't allow us to process DStreams after the invocation of stop. Is there any way to copy our last DStream so that we can access its objects after calling `stop()`?

The error we get while trying to do this is :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after stopping a context is not supported
```

The code schema is basically this:

```
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectKafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[" + CPUNumber + "]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

    //Some ml algorithms
    val x = b.map(something)
    ssc.start()

    ssc.awaitTermination()
    ssc.stop(false)

    //Some analytical tracking map reduce jobs
    val y = x.map(getanalytics)
```

Thanks in advance, any idea is very much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
b.foreachRDD(r -> stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted())
b.map(something)
b.foreachRDD(r -> System.out.println(stopwatch)
ssc.start()
```

then you can get time consuming in each rounds.

Comment: Yeah, but like I explained above, we have huge amount of data and we do not want to make the calculations based on measuring the efficiency in the streaming part. Your suggestion does that.

Comment: And believe me, it changes a lot in terms of the runtime, the analytic tracking reduce jobs even take more time than the ML algorithms themselves.